# Prev/Next Buttons in Bootstrap modal window to cycle through custom post types in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-modal

I have a "Featured Portfolio" gallery/carousel on my website (I'm using ACF for a lot of this). Clicking on the "More Info" button for each item triggers a bootstrap modal that provides more details about the project, including additional images. But I'd really love for the modal to have working prev/next buttons in the footer that go to the next/prev Featured item, like in the slider. I'm just not sure how to code this all. I'm assuming this involves a nested loop?  In any case, [here's](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/05e84d3739b00e7795d48a4bfa28ecb2) a link to a gist with my code as it stands right now. Everything so far is working swimmingly, so it's really only the prev/next links in the footer of the modal that I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: can you tried with fancybox popup?

Comment: No. Here's why: You're not supposed to have a bootstrap modal on top of another bootstrap modal, and within the main modal I'm then calling Fancybox for the image gallery.